# CsvHelper How can I save several classes in the same file

Tags: c#, csvhelper

How can I save several classes in the same file with CsvHelper? For example, through the different sheets. I tried like this but unfortunately it does not work.

```
using (var writer = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(@"db.csv")))
        {
            writer.WriteRecords(this.Class1List);
            writer.WriteRecords(this.Class2List);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
using (var writer = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(@"db.csv", true)))
    {
        writer.WriteRecords(this.Class1List);
        writer.WriteRecords(this.Class2List);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help

Comment: what error ? or why didn't it work..what is it doing?

Comment: When I trying to read saved file. I have Exception. "Additional information: The reader has already exhausted all records. If you would like to iterate the records more than once, store the records in memory. i.e. Use CsvReader.GetRecords<T>().ToList()" And the information is stored in a single list for all classes. http://i62.tinypic.com/99j491.png
I made a simple example. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ik5z2hhg6lgr0cu/WpfApplication4.rar?dl=0

Comment: so the streamwriter did what it was ment to....? your error comes from reading the saved file?

Comment: is the file saving correctly....? you just cant read it..or is the file not saving correctly?